# NULLs when importing flat file - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, null, ssms, flat-file

I am trying to import some data from a .csv file in SSMS using the "Import Flat File" option. However, not all the data is being copied.

Both data types are set to nvarchar(50).

The lines containing just a single value after the semi-colon is imported. Lines with multiple values are imported as NULL. I've tried separating the values with forward slashes and commas. The result is still the same.

How can I get the values imported instead of these NULL values?

[image]

Comment: This is a sample of data from a larger file. When I try to import this sample, everything works. The larger file results in the problem described above.

Comment: What do you mean by the lines with multiple values after semi colon? Is `;` or `,` your delimiter? If it's `;` then there is only **two** values on line 3,`963420` and `62,63,64,65`; the second string is a **single** value. If it's `,`, then your file is malformed.

Comment: The delimiter is ;

Comment: Yes, there are two values on line 3. But when I import, the second value is NULL

Comment: I'm guessing you set the second column to be a numerical data type? `'62,63,64,65'` isn't an `int`.

Comment: I set it to be nvarchar(50) because it contains commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my local machine with your example and everything is ok.

Maybe there is an issue in your flat file, have you checked your file is coherent (appropriate < CR >< LF > for example) in Notepad++ ?

Also, during the import, Is the result you see in the "preview" window correct ?

Comment: I tried to see in the preview window but I didn't have any data with commas in the first 50 lines or so. I moved some up and tried to import again and these were visible correctly in the preview. It is now correct in the table as well. Thank you. I am not sure why this fixed it though. Anyway, the preview window helped!